# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xyz.h': No such file or directory?

Tags: c++

I am using visual studio 2005 to create a project. And I have folder structure in project as: a folder called code. this folder contains all *.cxx files.

Now, I have created a class xyz in header file xyz.h. And defined every thing in xyz.cxx which is placed in code folder. 
But now when I try to compile it with visual studio it throws me an error 
"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xyz.h': No such file or directory". how to rectify this problem.

Comment: Where is `xyz.h` relative to the project and `xyz.cxx` files?

Comment: Is your header in the same folder as your code?

Comment: Are you using `#include <xyz.h>` or `#include "xyz.h`?

Comment: @DavidAlber no its not relative.

Comment: @Kevin no kelvin. it is like this. I have a project folder and in that folder i have a folder called code and xyz.h file. and in the folder code i have xyz.cxx. And i am using #include "xyz.h" in xyz.cxx

Comment: What I meant is `xyz.h` in the same directory as `xyz.cxx` or in a location that the project is configured to look for include files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either move the xyz.h file somewhere else so the preprocessor can find it, or else change the `#include` statement so the preprocessor finds it where it already is.

Where the preprocessor looks for included files is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  One solution is to put the xyz.h file in a folder where the preprocessor is going to find it while following that search pattern.

Alternatively you can change the #include statement so that the preprocessor can find it.  You tell us the xyz.cxx file is is in the 'code' folder but you don't tell us where you've put the xyz.h file.  Let's say your file structure looks like this...

```
<some folder>\xyz.h
<some folder>\code\xyz.cxx
```

In that case the #include statement in xyz.cxx should look something like this..

```
#include "..\xyz.h"
```

On the other hand let's say your file structure looks like this...

```
<some folder>\include\xyz.h
<some folder>\code\xyz.cxx
```

In that case the #include statement in xyz.cxx should look something like this..

```
#include "..\include\xyz.h"
```

**Update:** On the other other hand as @In silico points out in the comments, if you are using `#include <xyz.h>` you should probably change it to `#include "xyz.h"`

Comment: What about using forward slashes? Aren't backslashes only compatible with Windows?

Answer (score 22):

Add the "code" folder to the project properties within Visual Studio

Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories

Comment: yeah what you told is correct but it will rectify the problem locally. If i use the same project in other system I have to do it again.

Comment: @Apoorva I think you're thinking of Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ directories->Include Files?  Changing that setting does apply only to the instance of Visual Studio you modify.  The setting Holger is suggesting is stored in the vcproj file so when you move the project to another system the setting moves with it.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this error in a different situation, posting the resolution for those arriving via search: from within Visual Studio, I had copied a file from one project and pasted into another. Turns out that creates a symbolic link, not an actual copy. Thus the project did not find the file in the current working directory as expected. When I made a physical copy instead, in Windows Explorer, suddenly `#include "myfile.h"` worked.

Comment: can you give a little more detail. I'm basically in the same situation with a copy job but I'm a C# dev and new to C++

Comment: The key is that I was in Visual Studio, using Solution Explorer to copy-and-paste. This just created a symbolic link. Instead, you I had to open Windows Explorer in order to copy-and-paste the header file correctly.

Comment: Any idea why this works and how to workaround it without changing the source?

Comment: I haven't used C++ since this one project in 2011, and I don't know if current Visual Studio has the same behavior. Key lesson though: symbolic links in the project file are insufficient, need to have an actual copy of the file.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be easily solved by installing the following Individual components:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following approach helped me.

Steps :

1.Go to the corresponding directory where the header file that is missing is located. (In my case,../include/unicode/coll.h was missing) and copy the directory location where the header file is located.(Copy till the include directory.)

2.Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer->Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories.
 Paste the copied path here.

3.This solved my problem.I hope this helps !