# use of Log4cxx in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2012, log4cxx

I tried to build log4cxx for visual 2012 and, after 4 hours of resolving errors, the build was succesful (i'm not sure :)).

As a second step I tried to create a vs project to test logging.
I used [this example](http://www.dreamcubes.com/b2/software-development/10/log4cxx-tutorial-in-visual-c/) but it keep tell me that

> mainapp.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'log4cxx\logger.h': No such file or directory

I already specified in the linker the path of directory debug  in additional library directories and I added "log4cxx.lib" additional dependencies .

I'm confused and I don't know how to make it work

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: See also [fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xyz.h': No such file or directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7789969/33499)

Answer (score 2):

You also need to add the directory, where headers for log4cxx are. This is not for linking phase, but for compiler phase.

This can be done with Project Properties -> Compiler -> Preprocessor (I think, I don't have VS opened now)

**You don't include .lib. This file is for linking.**

You need to add to includes the directory, which contains directory `log4cxx`, and that (log4cxx) directory must contain `logger.h`!

Comment: thanks for your help ,i have already added the directories path in c/c++->general->additional include directories and additional #using directories

Comment: @user1842823 if logger.h is stored in `c:\libs\log4cxx\logger.h`, you need to add `c:\libs` to the include path. So not `c:\libs\log4cxx` in this example! But please specify where you have stored logger.h.

Comment: what i want to do is to use log4cxx.lib and in the my projet i include <log4cxx\logger.h> .i think if i add handreds of header files just for logging is meanless .

Comment: i searched tutorial how to use log4cxx in vs2012 but nothing

Comment: @user1842823 as Yossarian explained, this is a compiler error, not a linker error. So it is unrelated to the log4cxx.lib file.

Comment: yes i understand you but i still have the problem .any idea in the use of log4cxx will be useful

Comment: when i do this :<br/><br/>#include <log4cxx.lib>
#include <apr-1.lib>
#include <aprutil-1.lib>
#include <xml.lib>
#include <log4cxx\logger.h>
#include "log4cxx\xml\domconfigurator.h"
#include <windows.h>

 
using namespace log4cxx;
using namespace log4cxx::xml;
using namespace log4cxx::helpers;                                                   the original error diasppair but instead i had this :    <br/>  c:\log_cxx\apache-log4cxx-0.10.0\projects\debug\log4cxx.lib(1): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>c:\log_cxx\apache-log4cxx-0.10.0\projects\debug\log4cxx.lib(2): error C2018: etc

'

Comment: See the edit. And, learn something about C++ before trying to use any libraries.