# error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and OpenCV 3.0.0 . I get this error:

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp': No
>   such file or directory    C:\Users...\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\project_name\Source.cpp

when I use:

```
 #include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
```

I don't find xfeatures2d.hpp too! Any idea what is my problem?
I want to run this code:
https://github.com/OpenCVBlueprints/OpenCVBlueprints/tree/master/chapter_6/source_code/fingerprint/fingerprint_process/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xyz.h': No such file or directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789969/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-xyz-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Have you recompiled OpenCV with contrib modules?

Comment: `xfeatures2d` is not available in opencv 2.4.x. It is available from opencv 3.x onward.

Comment: I get same error with opencv 3.0.0