# A "fatal error C1083 " when trying to run a project in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

After compiling the whole project, I got a trouble when trying to build the task in Visual Studio code.
There appeared prompt in my terminal:
`"~\MicrosoftVisualStudio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: can't open the file: “crtdbg.h”: No such file or directory.` 
Please help me solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xyz.h': No such file or directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789969/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-xyz-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: If you use Visual Studio Community 2019 directly instead of Visual Studio Code does the same problem happen?

Comment: Related: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/958134/error-c1083-yvalsh-unable-to-include-crtdbgh.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/958134/error-c1083-yvalsh-unable-to-include-crtdbgh.html)

Comment: @drescherjm yes the same problem happened.

Comment: Then your problem is with your Visual Studio Community install. Perhaps the SDK installation.

Comment: @marsh-wiggle no i then added  "#include"crtdbg.h" to my code. it didn't help

Comment: @drescherjm but i could find  "crtdbg.h" here.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\